# How to evaluate $\int\left\{\log\left(\log\left(x\right)\right) + {1 \over \left[\log\left(x\right)\right]^{2}}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration

$$
\mbox{How to evaluate ?}\quad
\int\left\{\log\left(\log\left(x\right)\right) +
{1 \over \left[\log\left(x\right)\right]^{2}}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Hints or suggestions please.

Comment: Try with new variable?

Comment: log(x)=t? @MathIsTheWayOfLife

Comment: i was thinking that,how does it work out?

Comment: Btw, when you have ideas on a problem, usually the right thing to do is to try the idea and see if it helps. Usually, the wrong thing to do is try to figure out whether the idea helps before you try it.

Comment: You are right @Hurkyl

Comment: What does it mean to "evaluate" an indefinite integral? It is not a number nor a single function.

Comment: Well I'm a little weak in English(I'm not a native English speaker).You may edit it as you wish.Can you suggest another work to replace "evalute" ?@JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use integration by parts on $\int \log(\log x)dx $ twice .

$$\int \log(\log x)dx = x\log(\log x) - \int (1/\log x )dx $$

$$\int (1/\log x )dx = x/\log x + \int 1/(\log x)^2 dx  $$
Therefore,

$$\int \log(\log x) + (1/\log x)^2dx = x\log(\log x) -x/\log x $$